# disable double click on date value in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to disable double click on jquery UI datepicker date value. only one click should work to select the date value.

```
    $( "#issueDate" ).datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/date-picker.png",
          buttonImageOnly: false,
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          yearRange: '1950:2050',
          maxDate:"0",
          buttonText:"Select Date",
           onSelect: function(selected) {
              var issuedate = $("#issueDate").datepicker().val();
               $( "#dateOfBirth" ).datepicker("option","maxDate",issuedate);

                $(this).bind('dblclick', function() {
                       $('#dateOfBirth').val();
                    });


          }  


        });
```

Comment: remove `$(this).bind('dblclick', function() { $('#dateOfBirth').val(); });` and/or try [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. tried this but not working

Answer (score 1):

this might help:

```
onSelect: function(selected) {
              var issuedate = $("#issueDate").datepicker().val();
               $( "#dateOfBirth" ).datepicker("option","maxDate",issuedate);

                $(this).bind('dblclick', function(e) {
                      var e=e||window.event;
                       e.stopPropagation();
                       e.preventDefault();
                       return false; 
                   });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

*How to disable double click on jquery UI datepicker date value. only one click should work to select the date value.*

Try change this:

```
 $(this).bind('dblclick', function() {
     $('#dateOfBirth').val();
 });
```

to this:

```
 $(this).select();
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FH53h/)